# I need a Google Sheets formula that will count the dates and display total per month

Tags: google-sheets, count, string-formatting, number-formatting, google-query-language

I need a formula that will count the dates in column A and show how many of each month.

Example of the data in Column A

- 12/1/21
- 12/10/21
- 12/29/21
- 12/30/21
- 1/11/22
- 1/12/22
- 5/2/22

The returned data would be (or similar - I just need to know the total per month over the years)

- 12/21 - 4
- 1/22 - 2
- 5/22 - 2
- and so on.

Here is what I go so far.

```
=ArrayFormula(month('tab name'!A2:A10))
```

but this list the months and not counts them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(TEXT(A1:A, "mmm e"), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 <> 'Dec 1899' 
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col1)''"))
```

[image]

Comment: amazing, thanks. The only issue I see and can't figure out is

we do
month/day/year

I think you got it set to
day/month/year

how can I switch it to 
month/day/year

Example:
3/26/22

Comment: and since this sheet has been going on since 2019, how would you organize it by year? so Jan - Dec each year

Comment: @ZeJanIt try changing `mmm e` to `e mmm` - this will solve your year-ordering issue. also format `month/day/year / day/month/year` of A column does not matter if your dates are valid. you can check that with `=ISDATE(A1)` and drag it down. if all is TRUE you are safe